# Datos de API en React JS

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch

Estoy realizando una serie de pruebas para traer datos de una API en donde requiero que ciertas secciones del archivo JSON sean impresos en un PDF el cual se están trayendo por medio de un FETCH.

De esta manera estoy obteniendo los datos de la API

```
const [ factura, setFactura ] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/initalState')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setFactura(data));
}, []);
```

Hasta aquí no tengo ningún tipo de problema, me obtiene los datos excelente, pero ahora lo que necesito es imprimirlo hacia otro componente. Los valores de la API son los siguientes:

```
"initalState": {
  "companydata": {
      "nombre": "REPUESTOS ZENTENO Y COMPANIA LIMITADA",
      "detalles": "MANTENIMIENTO Y REPARACIÓN DE VEHÍCULOS AUTOMOTORES VENTA DE PARTES, PIEZAS Y ACCESORIOS DE VEHÍCULOS AUTOMOTORES VENTA AL POR MENOR DE OTROS PRODUCTOS EN PEQUENOS ALMACENES NO ESPECIALIZADO",
      "direccion": "CASA MATRIZ: AV.FREIRE 511 - Curico / E-MAIL: repzenteno@hotmail.com / TELÉFONO: 752314987"
  },
  "timbredata": {
      "rut": "78.305.030-7",
      "numfactura": "37535",
      "facturadate": "26 de agosto de 2018",
      "sii": "CURICÓ"
  },
  "receptordata": {
      "nombre": "COMERCIAL Y AUTOMOTRIZ ABRICAS LIMITADA",
      "rut": "76.758.902-6",
      "giro": "TALLER MECÁNICO",
      "direccion": "VIDAL 302",
      "comuna": "Curico",
      "ciudad": "Curico",
      "contacto": "CONTACTO",
      "telefono": "TELEFONO",
      "formapago":"FORMA DE PAGO"
  },
  "referenciasdata": {
      "tipodoc": "tipodoc",
      "folio": "folio",
      "fechaemision": "fechaemision",
      "motivo": "motivo",
      "otros": "otros"
  },
  "productosdata": {
      "codigo": "código",
      "descripcion": "descripcion",
      "cantidad": "cantidad",
      "precio": "precio",
      "adicional": "adicional",
      "descuento": "descuento",
      "valor": "valor",
      "bruto": "bruto"
  },
  "totalesdata": {
      "neto": "6597",
      "iva": "1655",
      "total": "5484",
      "adicionales": "6595",
      "impuesto20": "6624",
      "impuesto18":"656",
      "impuesto31": "6565"
  }, 
  "codedata" : {
      "codigo": "código"
  }
```

Ahora bien, ya que tenemos claro cuales son los valores dela API y que está trayendo adecuadamente los mismos, requiero que estos sean pasados a otros componentes donde serán impresos, es decir.. en el archivo JSON tengo la sección de productosdata, requiero que los campos que están asociados a el ean impresos en el siguiente componente.

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo de manera local con una constante en donde estoy pasando los datos, por eso lo tengo así, y en mi componente Table tengo lo siguiente:

```
const Table = ({productosdata}) => (
...
)}
```

Llamando sus valores (el de la variable constante) de la siguiente manera:

```
<TD><TT>{productosdata.codigo}</TT></TD>
```

¿Como pudiera hacer para insertar esos datos de la API en el componente?

Comment: Hola, obtenes esos datos en un componente A y queres pasarlos a un component B?

Comment: Buenas @cjara, eso es correcto, tengo un componente general en donde estoy llamando al resto, es deicr, los estoy construyendo, y por medio de ese componente general debo pasar por props los valores de la API al componente B

Comment: ¿Y eso te genera algún problema? o no está actualizando los valores de tú prop en el componente B?

Comment: El problema es ese @cjara, que no tengo ni idea alguna de como enviar los valores de esa API al componente según el objeto que yo quiera asignar. Porque lo he intentado haciendo un .map del objeto que requiero, pero no me funciona así.

Comment: Podes agregar un poco más de código para ver de que manera lo intentas, asi obtenes una mejor ayuda.

Comment: Es que el problema es ese, de la manera que lo he hecho es como si tuviera varios arreglos, pero no los tengo, tengo un solo archivo json con esa cantidad de secciones. No sé como obtener los datos por seccion e imprimirlos